# Attach to Process w3wp.exe not working for classic asp page

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, windows-10, w3wp

I am trying to debug .asp pages by Attaching to w3wp.exe, but my breakpoints do not get hit.

I have "Enable Client-side Debugging" & "Enable Server-side Debugging" & "Send Errors to Browser" all set to "True" on machine level, Default Website level, and website level.

For my application, I am using DefaultAppPool, which is v2.0 .NET CLR Version, Classic Managed Pipeline Mode, NetworkService Identity, and has Enable 32-bit Applications set to "True".

When I launch my website and go to "Attach to Process", w3wp.exe shows with "NETWORK SERVICE" User Name and "T-SQL, Managed, x86" Type. Sometimes I also see it showing just "x86" for the Type column, but I never saw it showing "Script" in the Type column (even though in "Attach to" window, I always keep "Script" or "Script" & "T-SQL" checked.

Please advise.

Comment: Classic ASP has been around a lot longer that VS, and I personally find that setting up debugging in VS is more trouble that it's worth, I just configure IIS to send detailed error messages to the browser.  In fact I rarely use VS at all for Classic ASP, it's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. a good text editor like EditPlus or Notepad++ does the job just fine

Comment: Make sure locate IIS ASP worker process (w3wp.exe on IIS) which exposes x86 and Script and attach as Script. Step: in IIS > ASP > Compilation > Debugging Properties > Enable Server-side Debugging.

Comment: I have "Enable Server-side Debugging" (as well as "Enable Client-side Debugging") set to "True" for all 3 levels: machine, Default Web Site, and the actual Application.

Comment: Try running it in .NET CLR v4.0,  that's what I have a site running in a Classic ASP dev environment, and I can attach and debug.  This will probably also have it running as x64